# Installing/Updating Programs on Server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, permissions

I'm accessing my server, which is hosted by JustHost, via a SSH in order to install Selenium in order to do some web-scraping.

I've run into an issue while trying to install it, however.

Judging by the error code, I believe I need to change the permissions of a particular directory, albeit my privileges are limited since I purchased shared hosting, so I'm wondering:

1. whether or not this is indeed an issue of permissions?
2. if so, what should I change the permissions to?
3. and lastly, is there any way getting around the limited privileges?

**Attempting Install of Selenium**

*Log*

`antonfa1@pillar.fyi [~]# pip install selenium
  You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 10.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  Collecting selenium
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/bc/17164fd471ccdf0df3a992c710c0c3c47743462ff41ab72a02c6ede96e90/selenium-3.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: selenium
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 308, in run
      strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 816, in install
      strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1013, in move_wheel_files
      strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
      ensure_dir(destdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 70, in ensure_dir
      os.makedirs(path)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium'`

*Permissions*

antonfa1@pillar.fyi [/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages]# ls -l selenium
/bin/ls: cannot access selenium: No such file or directory

So obviously the directory (and package?) is missing.

**When I go to update pip, I receive the exact same error.**

*Error*

`OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/bin/pip'`

*Permissions*

`antonfa1@pillar.fyi [/usr]# ls -l /usr/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 281 Jul  1  2015 /usr/bin/pip*`

So I tried installing Selenium via `pip install --user selenium` and here is what the console logged:

```
Collecting selenium
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/bc/17164fd471ccdf0df3a992c710c0c3c47743462ff41ab72a02c6ede96e90/selenium-3.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: selenium
Successfully installed selenium
```

Will the `InsecurePlatformWarning` mess with operations later on?

Comment: Short answer: " not really", but I'll update my answer in response

Comment: @baelx kk id really appreciate that! i'm still such a n00b when it comes to this stuff, sorry

Comment: Edited! I've responded as best I can, however, since your current issue isn't related to your initial question but more on python security as a whole, you may wish to look into this further and ask a separate question. Not having root access definitely complicates things when it comes to ensuring the security of your server. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a permissions issue and you won't be able to change permissions on a root-owned directory without root access yourself. There are however a few things you could do to install Selenium without root access:

You can try running `pip` with the `--user` flag which will install the package in your home directory rather than in **/usr/lib/python2.6** which is the default. So that's:

`pip install --user selenium`

Alternatively, you could also download the source distribution from [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) (if you're alright with the latest Selenium version), unpack the directory, `cd` into it, and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

This latter command shouldn't require root access to complete the installation.

---

**Edit:** Now that you've installed Selenium with the first provided-option and got that error, I'll break it down a bit.

This error isn't related directly to the specific install method you've chosen. In essence, it's a general message regarding your version of python. Older versions of python 2 lack [SNI support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) in their ssl module and are less secure overall. Ideally, you should consult [this guide on urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl-py2) and try to resolve the error which you *may* be able to do without access.

If you want to skip over all of that you could try switching to python 3 if that works for you. Check if python 3 is available on that machine by running `python --version`. You'll need to repeat your install steps by using the `python3` and `pip3` commands. i.e. `python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: i tried the first method and, although `Successfully installed selenium`, here is what the console logged out: (it's too long, i'll edit my question!)

Comment: unfortunately the hosting plan only permits python 2 :( the shell won't even let me upgrade pip :/ i'm not even sure if the server has a web browser installed on it, though i still need to get a webdriver on the server somehow. such a nightmare. i might try your second method?

Comment: @user2230470 If you're referring to downloading Selenium from source and installing via the `python` command with the setup.py file, it should show you the same error. As mentioned above, it doesn't matter what install method you choose: this is more an issue with your version of python as a whole. :/